# ruby convert BSON::hash to mongo strict json

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson

I would like to convert a bson hash to a query string which can be used for mongoexport.

For ex following hash to:

`{
'_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string("5375a4fb9356c2c27d000007")
'time' => Time.at(1438785734)
}`

to

`'{ "_id" : ObjectId("5375a4fb9356c2c27d000007"), "time": ISODate("2015-03-08T08:00:00Z")}'`

for python there is `json_util` method
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html
unable to find something similar in ruby